# How to import d3 library properly in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I am working with `d3` in order to visualize a force directed graph.

I started my project using a cdn file. But I found one problem, if I use this code:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js

..functions like `d3.forceSimulation()` are not available, at least it throws an error. So I changed the url to this one:

> https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js

...according to this example [Force-Directed Graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)

But new problem came out: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null`, that means, `svg`.

I tried to install `d3` using `npm`. So I imported `d3`:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
```

However, I cannot get how to append a svg to `div`

This is my code when error occurs:

***graphic/index.js***

```
// import modules
import * as d3 from 'd3'

// export function
const force_graph = (w, h) => {
  let svg = d3.select('#Gforce')
    .append('svg')
    .attr({
      'width': w,
      'height': h,
      'cursor': 'default'
    })

  let circle = svg.append('circle')
    .attr({
      'cx': 325,
      'cy': 270,
      'r': 10,
      'fill': '#7A6464',
      'class': 'dot'
    })
}

module.exports = force_graph
```

***index.js***

```
const graph = require('./graphic')
let w = document.getElementById('Gforce').offsetWidth
let h = document.getElementById('Gforce').offsetHeight
graph(w, h)
```

How can I import properly d3 library. I tried those options, but I cannot get any results. What am I doing wrong?

***EDIT 1***

I removed all d3 scripts from `html`.

I added this in my viz file:

```
const d3 = require('d3')
const d3SelectionMulti = require('d3-selection-multi')
```

I also tried:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import 'd3-selection-multi'
```

I used `.attrs` instead `.attr` according to docs: [d3-selection-multi v1.0.1](https://npm.runkit.com/d3-selection-multi?t=1497479018358)

This is the error it throws after those changes: `Uncaught TypeError: d3.select(...).append(...).attrs is not a function`

Comment: Are you using a plugin to allow you to assign attributes with just one `.attr({})` call? If `svg` is null after you do that, it could be related to the problem. Try console logging `svg` (it's probably undefined) before the line that starts `let circle=...`. Is it still undefined if you comment out the `.attr({...})` lines?

Comment: @anbnyc I am not using any plugin. If I comment `attr({...})` svg is now define.. What plugin would you recommend me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

D3.js v4 made breaking api changes. You're in version purgatory. You need to let go of v3 and embrace v4.

> functions like d3.forceSimulation() are not available

Because you were trying to use a v4 function that doesn't exist in v3.

> But new problem came out: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'append' of null, that means, svg.

Most likely it's because you're trying to use `attr` with an object, which v4 doesn't support out of the box.

You need https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi

Your import statement is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how can I use those libraries without so many `<scripts..>` Is there an option using `require` in node?

Comment: I think you just do `import 'd3-selection-multi';` after importing d3. It should modify the d3 prototype.

Comment: Thanks. I will look around. I don't know why it doesn't work. I edited the question with recent examples. Thanks again!